# How to extract Accuracy from caret's confusionMatrix?

Tags: r

I'm trying to just extract the Accuracy value from the confusionMatrix() output -- I've tried using the following:

```
    cl <- train.data[,1]
    knn.res <- knn.cv(train.data[,c(2:783)], cl, k = i, algorithm = "cover_tree")
    confus.knn.res <- confusionMatrix(knn.res, train.data[,1])
    confus.knn.res
    k.accuracy[which(k.accuracy[,2]==i),2] <- confus.knn.res$Accuracy
```

though just calling it as $Accuracy doesn't seem to work.

Comment: We will need a reproducible example or at least `str` of the data. We don't know if result of `confusionMatrix` is a data.frame or a list with column/element called `Accuracy`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm having trouble with as well. The output itself gives me a nice list of descriptive stats, but I'm not sure how to specifically access the Accuracy value. Here's an example with the iris data -- http://www.inside-r.org/node/86995

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the values of confusionMatrix() object is overall -- the first index of overall is the accuracy value. Therefore, it can be called as confus.knn.res$overall[1].

Comment: rfClassifier = randomForest(x = training_set[-1],
                            y = training_set$DV1, 
                            ntree = 100)

rfPredicted = predict(rfClassifier, newdata = test_set[-1])
# Confusion Matrix
rfConfMatrix = table(true = test_set[ , 1], pred = rfPredicted)
rfConfMatrix$overall[1]  # Error in rfConfMatrix$overall : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Answer (score 5):

Since `overall` is a named vector, the user-friendly way of doing this would be `confus.knn.res$overall["Accuracy"]`

Answer (score 0):

Although i am answering very late but still, it can help others to calculate all the parameters required. it can be done by retrieving values from confusion matrix and calculating by the following code:

```
    conf_train<-table(training$Activity, predictions) #from predicted values


    conf_train<-confusionMatrix(fit.knn,norm = "none")  
#from cross validation of training set, internal
RF.statistics_train = matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), nrow=3, ncol=5) 
colnames(RF.statistics_train )<- c('Precision', 'Sensitivity', 'Specificity', 'Accuracy', 'MCC')
rownames(RF.statistics_train) <- c('Class1', 'Class2', 'Class3')
for(i in 1:3)
{
  TP=conf_train$table[i,i]
  TN=0
  FP=0
  FN=0
  for(j in 1:3)
  {
    if(i!=j)
    {
      FP = FP + conf_train$table[j,i]
      FN = FN + conf_train$table[i,j]
    }
    for(k in 1:3)
    {
      if(i!=j && i!=k)
      {
        TN = TN + conf_train$table[j,k]
      }
    }
  }
  #  statistics[i,1] = conf_test[i,i]/col_total[i]
  #  statistics[i,2] = conf_test[i,i]/row_total[i]
  RF.statistics_train[i,1] = TP/(TP+FP)
  RF.statistics_train[i,2] = TP/(TP+FN)
  RF.statistics_train[i,3] = TN/(TN+FP)
  RF.statistics_train[i,4] = (TP+TN)/(TP+TN+FP+FN)
  RF.statistics_train[i,5] = (TP*TN-FP*FN)/sqrt((TP+FP)*(TP+FN)*(TN+FP)*(TN+FN))`
}
```

The code is for three class matrix but you can modify accordingly

Answer (score 0):

If one only requires the output values (i.e. Overall accuracy value) double brackets should be applied as below:

confus.knn.res$overall[[1]] #Overall accuracy is the first object!